# Downloading a large file on an iPhone (or any other iOS device)

Tags: iphone, ios

When attempting to download moderately sized zip files, a white screen is shown without a download progress bar.

I'd love to be able to do this without having to install any 3rd party software.

Does anyone know what file size limitation iOS has doer downloading ZIP file on an iOS device using mobile Safari?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Unlike a desktop browser, it is generally not possible to download files on an iOS device (save for special files which can be directly opened in the browser).

Comment: You don't see an option to open in the "Files" app?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Is wrong. I download very large files all the time to iOS. I’ve edited this to assume safari is doing the download / save to files. I have no issues with the files app and GB size files as well as downloading 800 MB files in Safari. My guess is it’s a problem on the specific web server serving the files. There are apps to do full SMB / cloud / NFS connection in addition to proper http - but I’m guessing this will be not an iOS limitation. We’ll see if some details can be edited in.